# Stata command: repeated cross section VS Panel

Tags: statistics, stata, linear-regression

I have a question regarding my understanding about repeated cross section and panel.

Is the Stata command `xtreg, fe` the same as `regress` and putting all possible fixed effects?
The Assumption here is: the dataset is a balanced panel.
So can I treat this panel as repeated cross-section when I put the fixed effects?

Comment: Should it be `regress` as the first editor suggested, or `reg` as you've written?

Comment: @TimWolla `reg` would work but `regress` makes it clearer.

Comment: yes, reg or regress, either way is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The slopes will be the same. This seems like an easy fact to verify. Compare the output of

```
webuse nlswork
xtreg ln_w age c.age#c.age ttl_exp c.ttl_exp#c.ttl_exp tenure c.tenure#c.tenure in 1/100, fe
reg ln_w age c.age#c.age ttl_exp c.ttl_exp#c.ttl_exp tenure c.tenure#c.tenure i.idcode in 1/100
```

You can use regress, though it's not computationally efficient. You will probably need to increase the matsize to at least N+K. You should also consider clustering your errors on the panel id.

You might also want to take a look at `areg`:

```
areg ln_w age c.age#c.age ttl_exp c.ttl_exp#c.ttl_exp tenure c.tenure#c.tenure in 1/100, absorb(idcode)
```

It is designed for datasets with many groups, but not a number of groups that increases with the sample size. The intercept will be slightly different too.

Comment: So, it is the same? The thing is I dont want to regress on my panel ID, since it is a group of countries and banks. And I want to put bank fixed effects and country fixed effects. Thus, I can only use reg, instead of xtreg. Am I right?

Comment: I would look into using a hierarchical model instead since the banks are nested in countries.